# Why is there a sudden increase in TTransportException?

Tags: evernote

We're recently receiving a lot of `com.evernote.thrift.transport.TTransportException` with HTTP codes 400, 429, 418.

429 corresponds to Too Many Requests but it was handled with `EDAMSystemException` `RATE_LIMIT_REACHED` before.

Comment: Seeing a lot of `Thrift::TransportException - Unexpected response content type: text/plain` errors using the Ruby SDK also. If I also capture the response code they're all `429`. Nothing's changed in our application (including rough usage amounts). Were changes made to the rate limit policies?

Comment: We're using the Java SDK and facing these errors.. I dont think it is resolved yet.

Comment: we get http code 429 in UserStore.getUser in https://github.com/robert7/nixnote2/issues/151

Comment: Folks, we are facing this issue again since Oct 2 2023. We've mailed evernote devsupport. Waiting to hear back. Anyone else facing the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We managed to make contact with Evernote developer support where they came to the realisation that a change their end was causing our issues.

We'd observed:

- rate limits being far stricter than normal
- rate limit errors being empty 429 responses, therefore not being picked up by the correct error handling on the SDK (we using Ruby)

Our issue is fixed now. My hope is that the change that fixed things for us has been rolled out to everyone, but if not I recommend emailing devsupport@evernote.com.